# Specifying PROJ.4 projection with North pointing down?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I would like to create a world map "upside down", with the South on top (in Mapnik).

How can I achieve this?

Can I take an existing projection string, e.g. Robinson projection, [ESRI:54030](https://epsg.io/54030).

```
+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

and flip/mirror it? So the North will point down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PROJ.4 trunk, there is [upcoming support](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/TMSO) for 'upside down' Mercator projections in Proj.4, which Frank [explains how to use](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Post-projection-affine-transformations-td5097157.html) as such:

> "proj trunk" does add new commandline
>   arguments for switching around the
>   axes that might be sufficient for your
>   mirroring needs.  If you can build
>   with trunk, you could try adding
>   something like:
>
> `+axis=esu`
>
> which means that the X axis is
>   "easting" the Y axis is "southing" and
>   the Z axis is "up".

Alternatively, you could do the rotation after the projection step, which seems to be what [Mapserver has implemented](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/MapRotation).

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some pointers. Some more resources I found on the topic (and arbitrary rotations): [Mapnik Ticket](http://trac.mapnik.org/ticket/531), [Discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/mapnik-users@lists.berlios.de/msg02432.html), [Rotating maps by transforming coords in the DB](http://www.ancalime.de/rotated.html)